# Dangers of converting file-based project to directory-based project?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a large Android project which was initially made in Eclipse thus being file-based project. I would like to convert it to IDEA's directory-based project, but I do not know which files will be changed in this process.

What are the dangers I should be aware of when converting file-based project to directory-based project?

Do any files get deleted in such conversion?

After the conversion, will Eclipse users be able to open the project or I would have to convert it back to file-based each time I need to share the project with such users?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both file based and directory based are IDEA specific project formats that Eclipse doesn't understand, therefore nothing will change in this regard after you convert.

When you convert a file based project to a directory based project, `.ipr` file is replaced with `.idea` directory and `.iws` file is moved to `.idea/workspace.xml`. Multiple different `.xml` files under `.idea` directory are easier to share/merge than a single large `.ipr` file.

Original `.ipr` and `.iws` files are not removed after converting, but it's a good idea to remove them manually to avoid confusion (like someone opening the old `.ipr` project instead of the new `.idea` directory based project).

Comment: Thanks. But Eclise work as file-based right? Because when I open Eclipse project in IDEA, I immediately have .ipr and .iws files.

Comment: No, Eclipse uses `.classpath` for storing dependencies and IDEA has an option to keep dependencies in `.classpath` (for modules). It's not related to file or directory based project formats.

Comment: Thanks. So when I open Eclipse project, convert it to directory-based project, Eclipse user will open it without noticing a change?